# Creating a list of lists from a df separated by row

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am currently trying to produce a lsit of lists for each row in a dataframe. Here is the code I have been using:

```
lst = [x[i].tolist() for i in df.columns]
```

However, this code will create a list for each column. Is there any way to separate it by row? So that I can have a list of values per column separated by row?

Comment: show us some sample data and expected output

Comment: There aren't many option so either `df.to_numpy().tolist()` or its transpose: `df.to_numpy().T.tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple loop that creates a list of list:

```
list_ = []
for x in range((df.shape[0])):
    list_.append(list(df.iloc[x, :]))
print(list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

initialize list of lists

```py
data = [['dogs', 10], ['cows', 15], ['bulls', 20]]
```

Create the pandas DataFrame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Animals', 'Total'])
```

print dataframe.

```py
print(df)
```